# Cannot convert value of type Substring to expected argument type String - Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

Trying to get substring of String and append it to array of Strings:

```
var stringToSplit = "TEST TEXT"
var s = [String]()
let subStr = anotherString[0 ..< 6]
s.append(subStr) // <---- HERE I GET THE ERROR
```

[image: error desc]

Comment: Just initialize a new String with your substring `s.append(String(subStr))`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As [@Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303865/leo-dabus) mentioned, you need to initialize a `new String` with your `substring`:

Change:

```
s.append(subStr)
```

To:

```
s.append(String(subStr))
```

Comment: Awesome - I was having difficulty figuring out how to convert a String.subsequence but this is simple and effective. Take my upvote

Answer (score 2):

my two cents for serro in different context.
I was trying to get an array of "String" splitting a string.
"split" gives back "Substring", for efficiency reason (as per Swift.org litre).

So I ended up doing:

```
let buffer = "one,two,three"
let rows = buffer.split(separator:",")

let realStrings = rows.map { subString -> String in
    return String(subString)
}

print(realStrings)
```

Ape can help someone else.